# How to declare an array of method references?

Tags: java, java-8

I know how to declare an array of other things, like strings, in this way:

```
String[] strings = { "one", "two", "tree" };
// or
String[] strings = new String[] { "one", "two", "tree" };
```

But when it comes to method references, I can't figure out how to avoid having
to create a list and add every item individually.

Example: Call the method `smartListMerge` on several diferent
matching lists from two sources:

```
List<Function<TodoUser, TodoList>> listGetters = new ArrayList<>(3);
listGetters.add(TodoUser::getPendingList);
listGetters.add(TodoUser::getCompletedList);
listGetters.add(TodoUser::getWishList);

TodoUser userA = ..., userB = ...;
for (Function<TodoAppUser, TodoList> listSupplier : listGetters) {
    TodoList sourceList = listSupplier.apply(userA);
    TodoList destinationList = listSupplier.apply(userB);

    smartListMerge(sourceList, destinationList);
}
```

What is the right way to declare an array of method references?

Comment: Do you want a List or an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are shorter ways to create a List:

```
List<Function<TodoUser, TodoList>> listGetters = Arrays.asList(TodoUser::getPendingList,
                                                               TodoUser::getCompletedList,
                                                               TodoUser::getWishList);
```

or (in Java 9):

```
List<Function<TodoUser, TodoList>> listGetters = List.of(TodoUser::getPendingList,
                                                         TodoUser::getCompletedList,
                                                         TodoUser::getWishList);
```

Comment: `What is the right way to declare an array of method references` - OP asks, `List#of` or `Arrays#asList` the answer :) +1, but still funny

Answer (score 1):

In your question, you asked of an array of methods. You can define it like this:

```
Method toString = String.class.getMethod("toString"); // This needs to catch NoSuchMethodException.
Method[] methods = new Method[] { toString };
```

Yet, in your example you work with functionals, which you can also put into an array:

```
Function<String, String> toStringFunc = String::toString;
Function[] funcs = new Function[] { toStringFunc };
```

Keep in mind to import `java.lang.reflection.Method` for the first or `java.util.function.Function` for the second example, respectively.

As far as I know, there is no shorthand for defining a list.

Comment: `Function[] funcs` should trigger a warning

Answer (score 0):

You can't *create* a generic array, but you can *declare* one (there is warning though):

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Function<String, Integer>[] arr = new Function[2];
arr[0] = String::length;
```