# Shorthand method for creating array of method references in Java 8?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, wicket-6

I'm using Wicket 6/Java 8 and am adding some simple classes that make use of the lambda functionality from Java 8 (I know the later versions of Wicket have lambda support but we can't upgrade right now).  I'm creating a LambdaModel that is a bit like the PropertyModel, which I'm hoping will remove the need to hardcode Strings representing the nested path to the property.

To start, I'm making a simple readonly version.  Ive made Serializable versions of the Function interface to create the following:

```
public class LambdaModelUtils {
  public static <X,R> IModel<R> ofNested( IModel<X> target, SerializableFunction<?,?>... path ) {
     // creates a model that works through each function in the path in turn
  }
}
```

My implementation works well, but the only problem is that calling this method the 'efficient' way causes compile errors:

```
IModel<Parent> parentModel = ...
IModel<String> model = LambdaModelUtils.ofNested( parentModel,
                            Parent::getChild, Child::getName );  // Compile time error
```

The only way I can find to call the method is by the following:

```
SerializableFunction<Parent,Child> path0 = Parent::getChild;
SerializableFunction<Child,String> path1 = Child::getName;
IModel<String> model = LambdaModelUtils.ofNested( parentModel,
                            path0, path1 );  // works
```

This is a bit clumsy - is there a better way?

Ive looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49235031/1298677) but this doesnt seem to work either:

```
List<SerializableFunction> path = Arrays.asList( Parent::getChild, Child::getName );
```

Thanks

Comment: Just curious... Why shouldn't you use lambda expressions where you're using method references?

Comment: Since `SerializableFunction<?,?>` would need unchecked casts to use, it is not better than using strings to represent properties, i.e. no compile-time safety at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using these functions to get to a nested property, but don't really use the intermediate results, I'd advice you to just use a lambda expression:

```
public static <X,R> IModel<R> ofNested(IModel<X> target, SerializableFunction<X, R> path)
```

```
IModel<Parent> parentModel = ...
IModel<String> model = LambdaModelUtils.ofNested(parentModel, p -> p.getChild().getName());
```

This works since the target type of the lambda is now known, instead of the generic `SerializedFunction<?, ?>`, you get `SerialiedFunction<X, R>` where `X = Parent` and `R = String`.

Comment: Could you share your SerializableFunction interface signature

Answer (score 1):

I tried something similar to your code. Casting the method references to the functional interface type solves the compilation error:

```
IModel<String> model =
    LambdaModelUtils.ofNested(parentModel,
                             (SerializableFunction<Parent,Child>) Parent::getChild, 
                             (SerializableFunction<Child,String>) Child::getName);
```

Not the prettiest solution, but at least it saves you the need to declare the `path0` and `path1` variables.